# Anti-responsive styling for mobile browser

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-safari

I have made a design for a website that is adapated for desktop visitors.

Naturally, for mobile visitors, the details get very small.

But I want to keep it like that, I don't want the mobile browser to try to zoom in on the website but retain the full width.

**What is key to accomplish this?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be what your looking for. Place it within the `<head></head>`

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=no">
```

set the content="" to whatever the size of the site is or what you would like it to be

Answer (score 0):

Include this line and set fixed width in your css not in percentage

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
```