# How to present desktop view for mobile visitors but still make it zoomable?

Tags: html, css, mobile, responsive-design, mobile-safari

Thanks to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20192563/anti-responsive-styling-for-mobile-browser) I have the following code in the `head`:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1024, user-scalable=no">
```

to force the elements to show full width and have the same look as on a desktop.

But with that code I can no longer zoom in on a mobile device, the width is firmly set.

**Is there a way to overcome this?**

Comment: Actually, you don't need the whole meta tag at all. but `user-scalable=no` speaks for itself, it disables the zoom.

Comment: I'm so embarassed... Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,minimum-scale=1,user-scale=0">
```

Answer (score 0):

From a comment:

"Actually, you don't need the whole meta tag at all. but user-scalable=no speaks for itself, it disables the zoom."